# Intel Realsense - unable to read bag file

Tags: python, intel, realsense

From the Intel Realsense camera D435i, I recorded a bag file and now trying to read it to fetch frames but getting the following error message:

```
RuntimeError: Couldn't Resolve requests
```

I am using python `read_bag_example.py` file example.

```
try:
    # Create pipeline
    pipeline = rs.pipeline()

    # Create a config object
    config = rs.config()
    # Tell config that we will use a recorded device from filem to be used by the pipeline through playback.
    rs.config.enable_device_from_file(config, args.input)
    # Configure the pipeline to stream the depth stream
    config.enable_stream(rs.stream.color, 1280, 720, rs.format.bgr8, 6)

    # Start streaming from file
    pipeline.start(config)

    # Create opencv window to render image in
    cv2.namedWindow("Color Stream", cv2.WINDOW_AUTOSIZE)
    

    # Streaming loop
    while True:
        # Get frameset of depth
        frames = pipeline.wait_for_frames()

        # Get depth frame
        color_frame = frames.get_color_frame()
        
        # convert frame to numpy array
        color_image = np.asanyarray(color_frame.get_data())
        cv2.imshow('Color Stream', color_image)
        key = cv2.waitKey(1)
        if key == 27:
           cv2.destroyAllWindows()
           break
finally:
   pass
```

NOTE: the bag file I recorded had depth and color stream at 6fps. In above code, I am just interested in color stream. I am assuming, it should not be a problem to fetch that.

Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: On which line is the error occuring? And is your file on your computer or on a remote server?

Comment: @Marco I too am getting the error at line:
`pipeline.start(config)`

Answer (score 0):

you can use  rs.format.bgr8 instead. like this

```
config.enable_stream(rs.stream.color, rs.format.rgb8, 30)
```

for more info,you can visit  https://github.com/IntelRealSense/librealsense/issues/2652